# How can I safely decide if a variable is a string of more than one characters?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following Javascript:

```
 if (typeof content !== 'undefined' && content.length > 0) {
    $state.transitionTo('admin.content', { content: content })
 }
```

I thought this was safe to use but it gives me an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

I am using the following function to decide if something is a number:

```
    isNumber: function (num) {
        // Return false if num is null or an empty string
        if (num === null || (typeof num === "string" && num.length === 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        var rtn = !isNaN(num)
        return rtn;

    },
```

How can I write a similar function that would very safely determine if 
something is a string with a length of more than 0?

Comment: So which one do you want, more than 0 or more than 1?

Comment: `if(content && content.length)`.. should work.

Comment: Erm, the clue is in your quesstion actually... `typeof content === "string" && content.length > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof num === "string" && num.length > 0)
{
  alert("You've got yourself a string with more than 0 characters");
}
```

Comment: @Alan No it will not. `typeof num === "string"` will evaluate to false if num is not a string. Because of the `&&` operator, the whole expression will be false if the first part is false, so as soon as that is the case, the second part will not be evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

`if (typeof(num) === "string" && num.length > 0) {...}`

Comment: No. Since the argument typeof is before the length, the if statement will first check the type of the variable. If it is a string, it will check the length and see if its bigger then one. Due to that, if your variables type is anything other then string, the if statement will check the type, see that it isn't a string, and go to your else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add upon the existing answers.
if string object is created through new constructor function then the following code will return false

```
var stringObj = new String("my string");

typeof stringObj === "string" // this will be false, because the type is object
```

a better way would be to test through the constructor property of the stringObj

```
stringObj.constructor === String
```

this condition will be true if the stringObj was created in the following two ways

```
var stringObj = "my string";
Or    
var stringObj = new String("my string");
```